# Why iterative loop to remove items in list stops

Tags: list, python-2.7, loops, indexing

New to Python, trying to understand how this iterative loop that is intended to remove all items form the list is handling the indexes in the list and why it stops where it does...

Why does this loop:

```
foo = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h']
for i in foo:
    foo.remove(i)
    print foo
```

Stop here?

```
['b', 'd', 'f', 'h']
```

Instead of here?

```
['H']
```

Also, what's happening "under the hood" with the indexes here?

With every iteration, is Python keeping track of which index is next while at the same time, once an item is removed the item to its right moves one index to the left (and that's why it's skipping every other item)?

Comment: Rule of thumb: don't modify things while you're iterating over them. It will almost never work.

Comment: You have to be careful when changing the data you are iterating through.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To understand why this is happening, **let us look step-by-step what is happening internally.**

**Step 1:**

```
>>> foo = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h']
```

Here, a new list object is created and is assigned to `foo`.

[image: step1]

**Step 2:**

```
>>> for i in foo:
```

Now, the iteration starts. `i` loop variable is assigned the value of item at **index 0** which is `'a'`.

[image: step2]

**Step 3:**

```
>>> foo.remove(i)
>>> print foo
['b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h']
```

Now, `.remove(i)` performs `.remove(foo[0])` and not `.remove('a')` apparently. The new list now has `'b'` at index 0, `'c'` at index 1 and so on.

[image: Step3]

**Step 4:**

```
>>> for i in foo:
```

For the next iteration, `i` loop variable is assigned the value of item at index 1 which is currently `'c'`.

[image: step4]

**Step 5:**

```
>>> foo.remove(i)
>>> print foo
['b', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h']
```

Now this time, `.remove(i)` performs `.remove(foo[1])` which removes `'c'` from the list. The current list now has `'b'` at index 0, `'d'` at index 1 and so on.

[image: step5]

**Step 6:**

```
>>> for i in foo:
```

For the next iteration, `i` loop variable is assigned the value of item at **index 2** which is currently `'e'`.

[image: step6]

**Step 7:**

```
>>> foo.remove(i)
>>> print foo
['b', 'd', 'f', 'g', 'h']
```

Now this time, `.remove(i)` performs `.remove(foo[2])` which removes `'e'` from the list. Similarly, the indices of the items gets changed as in step 5 above.

[image: step7]

**Step 8:**

```
>>> for i in foo:
```

For the next iteration, `i` loop variable is assigned the value of item at **index 3** which is currently `'g'`.

[image: step8]

**Step 9:**

```
>>> foo.remove(i)
>>> print foo
['b', 'd', 'f', 'h']
```

Now this time, `.remove(i)` performs `.remove(foo[3])` which removes `'g'` from the list.

[image: step9]

Step 10:

```
>>> for i in foo:
```

Now, `i` should point to item at **index 4** but since the original list has been reduced to 4 elements, the execution will stop here.

```
>>> foo
['b', 'd', 'f', 'h']
```

Above is the final list after execution.

**SOME CONCLUSIONS:**

- **NEVER CHANGE THE LENGTH OF LISTS WHILE ITERATING ON THEM.** In simple words, don't modify the original list while performing iteration on it.
- When performing `.remove()` in a list iteratively, the loop variable will refer to the list item using indexes and not by the actual items in the original list.

Comment: Thanks Rahul! That's an awesome explanation, very helpful indeed!

Answer (score 3):

It starts at index zero, removing the "A" there. It then moves to index one, removing the "D" there. (not "C", because that's at index zero at this point.) Then there are only two items left in the list, so it can't move on to index two, and the loop ends.

Perhaps instead of a `for` loop, you could use a `while` loop that continues until the list is empty.

```
foo = ['A', 'C', 'D', 'E']
while foo:
    foo.pop(0)
    print foo
```

... Or you could iterate over a copy of the list, which won't change from underneath you as you modify `foo`. Of course, this uses a little extra memory.

```
foo = ['A', 'C', 'D', 'E']
for i in foo[:]:
    foo.remove(i)
    print foo
```

Comment: OK, thanks! Using the enumerate() function would be a way to get around this, right?

Comment: I think `enumerate` will exhibit the same problem as your original code, actually.

Comment: You're right...Can you explain further why the loops stops with the list `['b', 'd', 'f', 'h']` instead of `['h']` ? Is that because it's "run out of indexes" so to speak?

Comment: Yeah, the principle is the same even with this new extended example. It skips every other item because the index moves forward by one each iteration even as elements are shifted leftward by your `remove` calls.

Comment: Ok, so even though there are still items left in the list, Python is saying, we're out of indexes, so the iteration stops? Is there a way to do this loop wherein Python is keeping track of both the items and where they're being moved as well as the indexes, such that it would only return one final item in the list?

Comment: I guess you could use either of the two approaches I laid out in my answer.

Comment: Sorry, my bad. The second example you included that uses `[:]` is really interesting. Would you mind explaining how that one works? Last question, i promise.

Comment: See the section on list slicing [here](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/introduction.html#lists). Supplying a colon and no values to the slice causes it to return a copy of the list with the same size and values as the original.