# Removing Items From List while iterating with For loop

Tags: python-3.x, database, list, for-loop

I am pulling values from my database and my variables in my list are in this form:

```
my_list = [<task1>, <task2>, <task3>]
```

I want to add them to a new variable:

```
new_list = []
```

When I do:

```
for x in my_list:
    print(x.task_urgency)
```

I get the value from all three rows, of the column value 'task_urgency'

```
for x in my_list:
    if x.task_urgency == "New!":
        my_list.remove(x)
        new_list.append(x)
```

When I iterate through, it doesn't find and delete all the values because of the way the indexing system works with removing values while in a for loop, but I need it to delete the certain ' for that value of x...

I am new to the values that are contained in <> and not sure how i can accomplish this.

Comment: Your answer is here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30651715/why-iterative-loop-to-remove-items-in-list-stops

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why iterative loop to remove items in list stops](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30651715/why-iterative-loop-to-remove-items-in-list-stops)

Comment: There *is* a simple explanation, which you almost certainly would have found in the hundred other questions detailing this had you searched on SO first :-)

Comment: @paxdiablo i tried, wasn't getting anything for the way i worded it

Comment: I just tried https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpython%5D+remove+list+iterate (`[python] remove list iterate`) and the top three links covered this situation. Not sure what your search terms were but I *do* know that, as Yoda would say, "strong is my Google-fu" :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution:

```
my_list = []
new_list = []
count = 0
for y in my_list:
    if y == "New!":
        count += 1
While True:
    if count > 0: 
        for x in my_list:
            if x.task_urgency == "New!":
                my_list.remove(x)
                new_list.append(x)
                break
     else:
         break
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
my_list = [task for task in my_list if task.task_urgency != "New!"]
```